# SeedStack "persistence.xml" not found using JPA add-on

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, persistence.xml, seedstack

I am setting up a SeedStack batch application and I am trying to use JPA without persistence.xml, but automatic JPA detection classes.

However, I had theses exceptions:

```
HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath 

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myUnit
```

I have this properties in application.yaml:

```
    # This configuration file can override main configuration for integration tests
    jdbc:
         datasources:
           myDatasource:
             provider: org.seedstack.jdbc.internal.datasource.HikariDataSourceProvider
             url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CNVT
             user: postgres
             password : admin
    jpa:
     units:
       myUnit:
         properties:
           hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
           hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update

    classes:  
        org:
          generated:
            project:
               domain:
                  model:
                     jpaUnit: myUnit
```

Also, when I add a persistence.xml, the JPA unit is created:

```
o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
org.seedstack.jpa.internal.JpaPlugin     Creating JPA unit myUnit from persistence.xml 
org.seedstack.jpa.internal.JpaPlugin     Created 1 JPA unit(s)
```

But, I had this exception:

```
org.seedstack.seed.SeedException: [SPRING] No spring entitymanager
```

I would like to use JPA with SeedStack properly without having to do a persistence.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the example [here](http://seedstack.org/addons/jpa/#configuration-1), your SeedStack JPA configuration is missing the reference to the datasource:

```
    jpa:
     units:
       myUnit:
         datasource: myDatasource
         properties:
           hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
           hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

The absence or presence of the `datasource` attribute is what makes SeedStack choose between `persistence.xml` based config or not (but it's not obvious).

In addition, the "No spring entitymanager" exception makes me think you have configured SeedStack to let Spring manage the JPA transactions (using `spring.manageJpa` config attribute). If that's the case, it's in contradiction with your SeedStack JPA settings.

In a SeedStack/Spring batch, you can either choose to:

- Let SeedStack manage JPA. In that case you configure JPA with SeedStack and use JPA (including @Transactional annotations) in SeedStack-managed code only (business services, repositories, ...).
- Let Spring manage JPA. In that case you configure JPA with Spring (without any SeedStack config) and set `spring.manageJpa` to true. This will allow SeedStack-managed code to use the Spring-configured JPA transaction manager.

Letting Spring manage JPA provides better performance during a Spring batch job, so I recommend the second option (but for batch jobs only).